# The multi-part identifier could not be bound SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables

I searched SO and Google for awhile but couldn't seem to find any that related to this error occurring in the set part of the code and if it did occur in that part, the solution didn't help me.

I am trying to use a user inputted weight and subtract it by the total weight. This equals the shrink

```
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight -  [ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk];
```

I also tried it this way and got the same error.

```
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk]);
```

The table is called `IC_ProductLots` and the alias is `ICPL`

The error I get is:

> The multi-part identifier "ICPL.OriginalQuantity_Stk" could not be
>   bound.

Here are my joins if that helps at all:

```
FROM 
    (((( IC_Products [PC] 
INNER JOIN  
    DC_Transactions [DCT] ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
INNER JOIN  
    AR_Customers ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
INNER JOIN  
    IC_ProductLots [ICPL] ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey)
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    IC_ProductCosts [ICP] ON ICP.ProductKey = PC.ProductKey 
                          AND ICP.ProductCostCode = 5)
```

Let me know if seeing any more code would help.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @PurchaseCost Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @InputWeight Decimal(19,8);
DECLARE @Shrink Decimal(19,8);

SET @PurchaseCost = 1;
SET @InputWeight = 20;
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight;

SELECT DISTINCT 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40)) AS [Supplier]
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , Count([ICPL].OriginalQuantity_Alt) AS [Boxes]
   , [ICPL].UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , Sum([ICPL].OriginalQuantity_Stk) AS [Weight]
   , [ICPL].UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost AS [Unit Cost]
   , Sum(ROUND([DCT].[Quantity_Stk] *[ICP].[UnitCost], 2)) AS [Total Sales]
   , Avg(([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk] / [ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Alt])) AS [Avg. Box Weight]
   , @Shrink AS [Shrink]
 FROM (((( IC_Products [PC] 
    INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
     ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey)
    INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
     ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
    INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
     ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
     ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5)
 WHERE 
    ([ICPL].ProductionDate >= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' }   AND ([ICPL].ProductionDate <= { ts '2015-06-24 00:00:00' } OR [ICPL].ProductionDate Is Null)) 
AND ((1=1)  AND AR_Customers.CustomerKey IN (124) ) 
 GROUP BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
   , [PC].ProductCode
   , [PC].Description1
   , [ICPL].UnitOfMeasure_Alt
   , [ICPL].UnitOfMeasure_Stk
   , [ICP].UnitCost
   , [ICPL].ProductionDate
   , AR_Customers.CustomerKey
 ORDER BY 
     CAST([AR_Customers].[CustomerCode] AS NVARCHAR(40)) + ' - ' + CAST([AR_Customers].[Name] AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

Would it be easier if I created another variable that calculated the sum of the original stock and then did `@InputWeight - @TotalSum`?

Sample Output:
Input weight 1,000

Product Code | Boxes | Weight | Shrink
1234         | 2     | 250    |       
2324         | 5     | 225    |       
3234         | 4     | 175    |       
4234         | 1     | 250    |       
______________________________________
Total:       | 12    | 900    | 100

The shrink is the difference of the input weight and the total weight. If it appears in every row that is okay, but the number should appear as 100 in every row if it follows this example.

Comment: Yes, I think more code would help!  You've done a good job of providing supporting information with your question, which already puts you ahead of the curve, but I do think that this would benefit from having a little more of your code included. Click the word 'edit' under your original question, and add it in!

Comment: Remove the parenthisis, that's for derived tables

Comment: @AHiggins I added the rest of my code for this report. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Austin!  Now, what exactly are you trying to do here?  Is `@Shrink` supposed to be the same value for all rows, or is it dependent on the individual sum of `[OriginalQuantity_Stk]`?  Perhaps a few sample output rows would be in order, here ...

Comment: @AHiggins Shrink is suppose to be the same value because it is InputWeight - sum[OriginalQuantity_Stk] so it should be the same value for the whole report. The shrink is based on the total weight for the report, not the weight of each individual item. Let me know if that makes sense or not.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running, here?

Comment: @AHiggins Microsoft SQL Sever 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing a field in a `SET` statement won't work - you need to actually `SELECT` the data at some point.  Without seeing more of your code, I can't offer any guarantees, but I believe that you are trying to do something like the following:

```
SET @Shrink  = @InputWeight - 
  (
    SELECT Sum([ICPL].[OriginalQuantity_Stk])
    FROM IC_Products [PC] 
        INNER JOIN  DC_Transactions [DCT] 
         ON [PC].ProductKey = [DCT].ProductKey
        INNER JOIN  AR_Customers 
         ON [DCT].CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey
        INNER JOIN  IC_ProductLots [ICPL] 
         ON [DCT].LotKey = [ICPL].LotKey
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  IC_ProductCosts [ICP] 
         ON ICP.ProductKey=PC.ProductKey and ICP.ProductCostCode=5
    WHERE ... -- add in your WHERE clause here
  )
```

Comment: When I attempt to do this I get an error with the system my company uses that says "Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status value."

Comment: I took out the parentheses - try again.

Comment: Edit 1 has the right idea, except the number it pulls is way off. It shows a number around five million every time.

Comment: Thanks for the information ... I'll put in a new proposal as Edit 3, which will only work if you have a recent version of SQL Server.  Edit 1 likely is off because I didn't include your `WHERE` clause and other stuff ... add in whatever you need to to make them identical.

Comment: Okay, that is what I was thinking. Except if the where clause is dynamic, such as the date will change per report as well as the customer key how would I implement that?

Comment: Handle it the same way you do your regular report's `WHERE` clause ... variable or parameter would be my assumption.

Comment: Alright so I am confused. ProductLots is already joined correct? Because now when I try to add the where clause I am getting the The multi-part identifier "IC_ProductLots.ProductionDate" could not be bound. But since ProductLots is already in my from statement shouldn't it be okay? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: It's there, yes, but you gave that table the alias ICPL.  Once you've done that, you can't reference it by the 'real' name.